# Retrieve Year and week number from date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-date-functions

I am trying to fetch the year number and week number in the format `yyyyww` like `201901`, `201905`, `201911` etc and I am using this query to do it:

```
declare @BeginDate datetime

set @beginDate = '2019-02-07'

select  
     concat(datepart(year, @BeginDate), right('0' + convert(varchar, datepart(week, dateadd(day, -7 , @BeginDate))), 2))
```

This worked fine till 2018 December. But when I try this for the date `2019-01-07`, it returned `201953` which is not correct. But for all other values like 2019-01-14 etc it's fetching the week number correctly.

So how can I fetch the year week number combination accurately all over the year

Comment: Why are you subtracting 7 days from the begin date?  Note that the `WEEK` date part is not necessarily as clean as you think.  A given year may have either 52 _or_ 53 weeks in it, due to that 52 weeks is only 364 days, and a year may have either 365 or 366 days.  You should define how you want to count a week.

Comment: Might I ask why you have this particular requirement? It's a valid question, but it seems like an awful lot of string/date jiu-jitsu for something as pedestrian as a composite value. You might be able to get at what you need in a better or easier way.

Comment: 2019-01-01 belongs to 53rd week of 2018... this all depends on the definition of first week of year.

Answer (score 6):

You're not considering the 'year week' definition:

According to Wikipedia:
*First year's week is the week containing the first Thursday of the year or either the week containing the 4th of January or either the week that begins between 29th of Dec. and 4th of Jan.*

So if year begins with week number 52 or 53 that is the trailing of previous year's last week.

so you have:

```
set dateformat ymd 
set datefirst 1
declare @data as datetime
declare @year as int

set @data = cast('2017-01-01' as datetime)
set @year = case when datepart(iso_week,@data) >= 52 and month(@data) = 1 
                      then year(@data)-1 
                 when datepart(iso_week,@data) = 1 and month(@data) = 12 
                      then year(@data)+1
                      else year(@data) end

select concat (@year, right('0'+cast(datepart(iso_week,@data) as varchar(6)),2))
```

result of this is `201652`

edit: updated to have always double-digit week

Answer (score 4):

You can try by using following code

```
SELECT concat(year('2019-01-07'),Format(datepart(day, datediff(day, 0, '2019-01-07')/7 * 7)/7 + 1 , '00') )
```

output

```
201902
```

or

```
SELECT concat(year('2019-01-01'),Format(DATEPART( wk, '2019-01-01')  , '00') )
```

output

```
201901
```

Comment: This code is faulty: tested with `2017-01-01` returns `201704` that is surely wrong, dbfiddle to it: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f68026566c42fec1537a98c346af13ce

Comment: Now it says week 201701 but it still faulty because 1-1-2017 is week 201652.

Comment: @DDS i have written code for specific format (yyyy-mm_dd) because user asked specific format

Comment: @I've seen, but that is not a problem (also you can simply `set dateformat ymd`) to make clear the format you're using

Comment: Also your code have issues in dates like 2021-01-01 that is 202053 but your code reports it as 202105

Comment: @DDS now what is the problem yaar my second solution is working know already u marked my answer downvote i have corrected because u found the mistake i have to give you any medal

Comment: The problem is that your year always starts with week 01, that is not true, at least on most of the world, where a year may start with previous year's last week

Answer (score 1):

Normally the clearer way of calculating standard parts of a date is by using the standard functions.
So, I propose to use DATEPART combined with RIGHT to ensure we have the two characters starting per the right:

```
DECLARE @DT AS DATE = '2019-01-07'
SELECT  CONCAT(year(@DT),
        RIGHT('0'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(wk, @DT)), 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Below block of code is not the exact solution, but it definitely help you..

## SQL

```
DECLARE @Dt datetime

SELECT @Dt='02-21-2008'

SELECT DATEPART( wk, @Dt)
```

Comment: this will return week values like 1,2,etc . I need them as 01,02 etc

Comment: User Format function to get result as expected                                          
           SELECT Format(DATEPART(wk, @Dt), '00')