# Convert date and week of day to calendar format using pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have the following data in the temp table

[image]

I want it to convert into the calendar format using pivot as

[image]

but due to aggregate it only shows 1 row

```
 SELECT
     *
 FROM
     (SELECT
          CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dt, 106) AS Date1,
          dw AS Wd
      FROM
          #tbl) t 
 PIVOT
     (MAX(Date1)
         FOR Wd IN ([Sunday], [Monday], [Tuesday], [Wednesday],[Thursday], [Friday], [Saturday]) 
     ) AS pivotTable
```

[image]

as per the comments, I have following update

```
  With CTE (dt,dw,last)
as
(
select Cast(dateadd(day, -day(GetDate())+1,GetDate())as date),datename(dw,Cast(dateadd(day, -day(GetDate())+1,GetDate())as date)),
cast(dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(Month,1,Cast(dateadd(day, -day(GetDate())+1,GetDate())as date))) as date)
union all
select cast(dateadd(day,1,dt) as date), DATENAME(DW,cast(dateadd(day,1,dt) as date)),last
from CTE
where cast(dateadd(day,1,dt) as date)<last
)
select * from (
select dt,dw,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by dw order by dt) as RN
 from CTE
)t
pivot(
Max(dt)
for dw in ([Sunday],[Monday],[Tuesday],[Wednesday],[Thursday],[Friday],[Saturday])
) as Pt Option (MAXRECURSION 31)
```

The problem is that, pivot is not considering the last day of the month for some reason as you can see in the screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Good question, thanks for the brain teaser. For the next time, please (1) format your SQL (so that the editors don't have to do it for you) and (2) provide the test data as INSERT INTO statements instead of a screen shot (so that the answerers don't have to do that before being able to help you).

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got, the solution, the last day was missing because of the where statement in my CTE, it should be less than or equals to max date.

```
    With CTE (dt,dw,last)
as
(
select Cast(dateadd(day, -day(GetDate())+1,GetDate())as date),datename(dw,Cast(dateadd(day, -day(GetDate())+1,GetDate())as date)),
cast(dateadd(day,-1,dateadd(Month,1,Cast(dateadd(day, -day(GetDate())+1,GetDate())as date))) as date)
union all
select cast(dateadd(day,1,dt) as date), DATENAME(DW,cast(dateadd(day,1,dt) as date)),last
from CTE
where cast(dateadd(day,1,dt) as date)<=last
)
select * from (
select dt,dw,ROW_NUMBER()over(partition by dw order by dt) as RN
 from CTE
)t
pivot(
Max(dt)
for dw in ([Sunday],[Monday],[Tuesday],[Wednesday],[Thursday],[Friday],[Saturday])
) as Pt Option (MAXRECURSION 31)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to "group by" something unique to the row. In your case, since you want one row per week, that would be the week number.¹ In a pivot table, that "grouping" is achieved by just adding the relevant field to your data source:

```
SELECT [Sunday],[Monday],[Tuesday],[Wednesday],[Thursday],[Friday],[Saturday]
  FROM (SELECT dt, dw, DATEPART(wk, dt) AS week_nr
          FROM #tbl
       ) AS t
 PIVOT (MAX(dt)
        FOR dw in ([Sunday],[Monday],[Tuesday],[Wednesday],[Thursday],[Friday],[Saturday])
       ) AS pivotTable
```

Result:

| Sunday | Monday | Tuesday | Wednesday | Thursday | Friday | Saturday |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-05-01 | 2022-05-02 | 2022-05-03 | 2022-05-04 | 2022-05-05 | 2022-05-06 | 2022-05-07 |
| 2022-05-08 | 2022-05-09 | 2022-05-10 | 2022-05-11 | 2022-05-12 | 2022-05-13 | 2022-05-14 |

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/cdf3e1/6/0

---

¹ Obviously, if you want your calendar to span multiple years, you'll need the ["week year"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54248251/87698) as well.

Comment: It is not giving me the last day of the month, rest is fine.